# VirtualHost for subfolder only in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, directory

I have an Apache2 server. Most of my sites use PHP. One uses Ruby on Rails. So I want passenger in one subfolder.

How can I tell Apache to make a virtual host in just one subfolder for passenger? I've only seen examples where the virtual host is on a specific IP or subdomain.

Thanks,
MrB

Answer (score 1):

Check passenger documentation [3.2. Deploying to a sub URI](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri)

Comment: Yea that didn't work. I already tried that. It just gets ignored if I turn "PassengerEnabled off".